# ¿Cómo envíar los datos de un $request a una vista?

Tags: laravel

Recibo en mi controlador un `$request` y deseo que esos mismo datos se envíen a otra vista, lo hago de esta manera pero no es la correcta:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $visits =  Visit::leftjoin('users', 'visits.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->selectRaw('visits.id as vid, users.name as uname, visits.first_name as vfn, visits.last_name as vln, visits.cuit as vc, DATE_FORMAT(visits.created_at, "%d-%m-%Y") as date, TIME(visits.created_at) as hour')
            ->search($request)
            ->paginate(12);

    return view('admin.dashboard.visits.admin-index', compact('visits', 'request'));
}
```

Cómo podría envíarlo?

Comment: ¿A quñe te refieres con que no es la correcta?, si puedes explicar mas ampliamente el problema y dar mas contexto te lo agradeceremos mucho

Comment: Debes hacer algo como esto `$variables = $request->all()`

Comment: graciasnuevamente